minha função Def não está funcionando
Olá, estou tentando fazer uma classe com objetos usando a função def na IDE do visual studio code. Porém ao executar esse código o terminal não me retorna nada, não retorna nenhum erro no código e nem nada, simplesmente fica vazio. Gostaria de saber o que eu estou fazendo de errado? Segue abaixo o código:
class Produto:
  def__init__(self, nome, valor, marca, = ‘ ‘, modelo = ‘ ‘):
self.nome = nome
self.valor = valor
self.marca = marca
self.modelo = modelo

produto0 = Produto(‘celular’, 4000, ‘apple’, ‘Iphone 13 pro’)

print(produto0.dict___)


Além do recuo do código não estar adequado, onde escreveu def__init__ falta espaço entre a palavra chave def e o identificador __init__.

O código acima contem alguns problemas são eles:

Indentação
Falta um espaço após def
O tipo de aspas deve ser ' não ‘
Uma virgula errada aqui marca, = ' '
O correto é __dict__

Segue abaixo o código como deveria ser:
class Produto:
  
    def __init__(self, nome, valor, marca = '', modelo = ''):
        self.nome = nome
        self.valor = valor
        self.marca = marca
        self.modelo = modelo
    
produto0 = Produto('celular', 4000, 'apple', 'Iphone 13 pro')

print(produto0.__dict__)

Aqui um link do código rodando
